# Русификация переменной из

Tags: c#

```
<Setting Name="ManifestUl" Type="System.String" Scope="Application">
<Value Profile="(Default)">localhost/1.data</Value>
</Setting>
```

Как я могу русифицировать ManifestUl вы вывода

Comment: А? ничего не понял

Comment: @АндрейNOP ну чтобы при при использование ManifestUl писало мой текст, а не ManifestUl